# how to pass list as parameter in function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have taken a list and insert some value in it

```
public List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();         
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(12/1/2012);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(12/6/2012);
if (dt1 <= dt2)
{                              
    for (DateTime dt = dt1; dt <= dt2; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
    {
        dates.Add(dt);                    
    }       
}
```

Now I want pass this List i.e dates as a parameter to some function like-

```
somefunction(dates);
```

How exactly can i achieve this?

Comment: @Mir - My quick search led me to this question.  So +1 from me to the OP who's been downvoted.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to do it like this,

```
void Yourfunction(List<DateTime> dates )
{

}
```

Answer (score 10):

You should always avoid using `List<T>` as a parameter. Not only because this pattern reduces the opportunities of the caller to store the data in a different kind of collection, but also the caller has to convert the data into a `List` first.

Converting an `IEnumerable` into a `List` costs O(n) complexity which is absolutely unneccessary. And it also creates a new object.

TL;DR you should always use a proper interface like `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` based on what do you want to do with your collection. ;)

In your case:

```
public void foo(IEnumerable<DateTime> dateTimes)
{
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
public void SomeMethod(List<DateTime> dates)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pass it as a `List<DateTime>`

```
public void somefunction(List<DateTime> dates)
{
}
```

However, it's better to use the most generic (as in general, base) interface possible, so I would use

```
public void somefunction(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
{
}
```

or

```
public void somefunction(ICollection<DateTime> dates)
{
}
```

You might also want to call `.AsReadOnly()` before passing the list to the method if you don't want the method to modify the list - add or remove elements.

Comment: Look at the code in the question. It creates a list of dates and adds individual dates to it.

Answer (score 2):

I need this for **Unity** in C# so I thought that it might be useful for someone. This is an example of passing a list of AudioClips to a function called `ChooseClip`:

```cs
private void ChooseClip(GameObject audioSourceGameObject , List<AudioClip> sources) {
    audioSourceGameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().clip = sources [0];
    }
```