# Passing a List, with a predefined structure, as parameter to a different Form

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters

I've seen this issue in several links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135758/non-invocable-member-cannot-be-used-like-a-method), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020846/non-invocable-member-cannot-be-used-like-a-method) but I believe that my case is a little bit different.

I wanna pass to a second form a list which will be upload to the database.

The structure of the list is:

```
    public struct GraphData
    {
        public double Temp1;
        public double Temp2;
        public DateTime Date;
        public string Type;
    }
```

The list is populated like this:

```
    for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
    {
        GraphData update = _listData[i];
        update.Type = type;
        _listData[i] = update;
        chart1.Series[0].Points[i].Color = color;

        // add to a list so we can save on the DB if the user wants
        PointsAndCycles.Add(new GraphData()
        {
            Temp1 = update.Temp1,
            Temp2 = update.Temp2,
            Date = update.Date,
            Type = update.Type
            // CAN I ALSO HAVE THE ID?
        });

    }
```

I am trying to pass a list like this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Database.SavePointsAndCyclesListIntoDB(List<GraphData> PointsAndCycles) ;
}
```

But I am getting the error:
CS0305  C# Using the generic type 'List' requires 1 type arguments and CS0119  C# is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Extra information... In the second form I will execute the list like this:

```
   public void SavePointsAndCyclesListIntoDB(List<GraphData> PointsAndCycles)
    {
        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConection))
        {
            try
```

Can anybody help me? I took this idea, of passing as parameter, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993371/how-to-pass-list-as-parameter-in-function)

If I try:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Database.SavePointsAndCyclesListIntoDB(PointsAndCycles) ;
}
```

I get the error:

```
 System.Collections.Generic.List<A_Dev_.Analysis.FormA_DataType.GraphData>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<A_Dev_.Database.ClassDatabase.GraphData>'
```

Finally, I am trying to make the list public this way:

```
public List<GraphData> PointsAndCycles = new List<GraphData>();
```

Extra:
Inside the ClassDatabase, I also defined GraphData like this

```
public struct GraphData
{
    public double Temp1;
    public double Temp2;
    public DateTime Date;
    public string Type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems with this, the first is with the form of your function call...

If that was the only problem you could just do this

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Database.SavePointsAndCyclesListIntoDB(PointsAndCycles) ;
}
```

You declared a type within a function call.

The other problem is that `PointsAndCycles` doesn't seem to be a part of the current scope, unless it's contained in the class containing the function. You need to figure out a way to access the `List` within the event handler, possibly through `e` or `sender` depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Hey, I just added this try. It did not work. I am passing "PointsAndCycles" as public.

Comment: I tried two ways. The first with "public List<GraphData> PointsAndCycles = new List<GraphData>();" error -  Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dev_.Analysis.FormA_DataType.GraphData>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dev_.Database.ClassDatabase.GraphData>';; If I try         public List<GraphData> PointsAndCycles { get; set; } I get the same error.

Comment: Are the event handler and list in the same class?

Comment: Yes, both are in the same form. What it is in the other form it is the SavePointsAndCyclesListIntoDB;